# Windows SDK 7.0A and 7.1 error: Absolute path information required

Tags: windows, winapi

I've searched and tried to solve this on my own for a while but I cannot seem to get the Windows SDK 7.0A nor 7.1 to install. Prety much as soon as I execute the setup (NOTE: ISO or web installer) I get the error message "Absolute path information required". Even after I close the message I can see the setup leaving two processes in task manager until I kill them myself - Setup.exe and SetupSDK.exe.

I have found someone who solved similar problem by changing paths in registry for ProgramFilesDir, but in my case it looks correct. I noticed though in my environment variables that the TEMP and TMP were not absolute paths, so I changed them to absolute ones, rebooted computer and tried again but to no avail.

The setup does not even seem to create a log file before the error occurs. Any ideas?
It is a remote PC running Win7 x64

Comment: What is the TEMP variable, and is any other previous versions of SDK installed?

Comment: This is a sick machine syndrome, typically a dirty registry problem.  Remnants of a previous install that failed or wasn't uninstalled properly, something like that.  You might see something with SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: Define "remote PC" and how you're accessing it. Are you running the install via Remote Desktop/Terminal Server, or running it on your local machine trying to place the installation on a remote system?

Comment: @cDima The TEMP and TMP variable are set to C:\windows\temp. They were both set to non-absolute paths earlier, so I changed them to this value instead, but it did not seems to help. Trying to find out which path it really is complaining about. But to no avail so far. :/

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, I should have been more clear. By remote I mean a PC accessed via Remote Desktop over VPN. Once logged in via RD on that machine I try to run the install locally. But since I was not the one who performed the initial installation and configuration of Windows 7 on that machine I cannot know what has previously been installed on it. But, with the error message in mind (and that the install immediately fails with that message) it seems like some path to some folder in registry might not be what it expects. Only...which path?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, something is not right, but the installation of many other applications went just fine (such as Visual Studio). I can see there is a MictosoftSDK folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\ with version 7.0A, but I cannot find any entry for it in "Programs and Features" in Control Panel. Still, the error message, and the fact that it appears so quickly after I launch the setup, makes me think the error is path related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally solved the problem! *Phew* :D
Turns out I was on the right track at least, and I shall provide the answer which helped me, especially since I could only find one related error when searching the web, concerning Windows SDK, and it was not able to solve my problem.

Solution which worked for me:

1. Go to regedit.exe
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
3. Make sure basically that every folder there starts its path with "%USERPROFILE%\"
4. Run Setup again and voila!

In my case, the "Desktop" and "Favorites" entries were set to being only "\Desktop" and "\Favorites" respectively, for some reason. By changing them to "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" and "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" I could then run the setup successfully.

Hope this might help someone else!

Comment: As a comment though, I really think Microsoft should start the logging process a bit earlier in the execution of setup...